# How to add a object's field in another Object to display it in jsp

Tags: hibernate, list, jsp, arraylist

I am getting a UserList by following

```
List<User> UserList=usersService.findUsers();
```

than am iterating over this list and based on `id` getting another object `UserActivity`, and want UserActivity object's field LastSeen_time.

```
 Iterator<User> iterator = UserList.iterator();
         while(iterator.hasNext()){
                 User user= iterator.next() ;
                 System.out.println("userA"+user.getId());
                 UserActivity userActivity  =  userActivityService.findUser(user.getId());
                 System.out.println("userActivity"+userActivity.getLastSeen_time());


         }
```

Now i want to pass User and UserActivity.LastSeen_time to a jsp page, where i will display it as

```
User.name User.id UserActivity.LastSeen_Time(corresponding time for each id)
```

How can i do it, Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the necessary information in the request scope. For user activities, easiest is to have a `Map<Long, UserActivity> userActivities` with user ID as key. You can then access it in EL using `${userActivities[user.id]}`.

E.g.

```java
List<User> users = userService.list();
Map<Long, UserActivity> userActivities = new HashMap<Long, UserActivity>();

for (User user : users) {
    userActivities.put(user.getId(), userActivityService.findByUser(user));
}

request.setAttribute("users", users);
request.setAttribute("userActivities", userActivities);
```

and then in JSP

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User name</th>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>Last seen time</th>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
      <td>${user.id}</td>
      <td><fmt:formatDate value="${userActivities[user.id].lastSeen}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

*(I'm assuming that `getLastSeen()` returns a `Date`)*